# Scrapy gets blocked even with Selenium; Selenium on its own doesn't?

Tags: selenium, web-scraping, scrapy, http-status-code-403

I am trying to scrape data off a website. Scrapy on its own didn't work (I get HTTP 403), which led me to believe there are some UI-based countermeasures (e.g. checking for resolution).

Then I tried Selenium; a very basic script clicking its way through the website works just fine. Here's the relevant excerpt of what works:

```
driver.get(start_url)
try:
  link_next = driver.wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located(
    (By.XPATH, '//a[contains(.,"Next")]')))
  link_next.click()
```

Now, in order to store the data, I'm still going to need Scrapy. So I wrote a script combining Scrapy and Selenium.

```
class MyClass(CrawlSpider):
    ...
    start_urls = [
      "domainiwanttocrawl.com?page=1",
    ]

def __init__(self):
    self.driver = webdriver.Firefox()
    self.driver.wait = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 2)

def parse(self, response):
    self.driver.get(response.url)

    while True:

      try:
        link_next = self.driver.wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//a[contains(.,"Next")]')))
        self.driver.wait = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 2)
        link_next.click()

        item = MyItem()
        item['source_url'] = response.url
        item['myitem'] = ...

        return item

      except:
        break

    self.driver.close()
```

But this will also just result in HTTP 403. If I add something like `self.driver.get(url)` to the `__init__` method, that will work, but nothing beyond that.

So in essence: the Selenium get function continues to work, whereas whatever Scrapy does under the hood with what it finds in `start_urls` gets blocked. But I don't know how to "kickstart" the crawling without the `start_urls`. It seems that somehow Scrapy and Selenium aren't actually integrated yet.

Any idea why and what I can do?

Comment: Scrapy and Selenium are indeed not integrated. Scrapy is meant to be doing its own HTTP requests. If you do Selenium calls within Scrapy spider methods, it will not automagically convert them to Scrapy `Response` instances. So whatever is in `start_urls` will go through Scrapy's downloader, not through Selenium, therefore showing the same 403s.

Comment: Thank you. But how can I then integrate them, so that any interaction with the server will go through Selenium? Or is that just not possible?

Answer (score 1):

Scrapy is a pretty awesome scraping framework, you get a ton of stuff for free. And, if it is getting `403`s straight out of the gate, then it's basically completely incapacitated.

Selenium doesn't hit the `403` and you get a normal response. That's awesome, but not because Selenium is the answer; Scrapy is still dead-in-the-water and it's the work-horse, here.

The fact that Selenium works means you can most likely get Scrapy working with a few simple measures. Exactly what it will take is not clear (there isn't enough detail in your question), but the link below is a great place to start.

[Scrapy docs - Avoid getting banned](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/practices.html#avoiding-getting-banned)

Putting some time into figuring out how to get Scrapy past the `403` is the route I recommend. Selenium is great and all, but Scrapy is the juggernaut when it comes to web-scraping. With any luck it won't take much.

Here is a util that might help: [agents.py](https://gist.github.com/tiffon/c590a24e5b782ff711622da0cc7f738c) It can be used to get a random user agent from a list of popular user agents (circa 2014).

```
>>> for _ in range(5):
...   print agents.get_agent()
...
Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/36.0.1985.125 Safari/537.36
Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/36.0.1985.125 Safari/537.36
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/36.0.1985.125 Safari/537.36
Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 7_1_2 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/537.51.2 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/7.0 Mobile/11D257 Safari/9537.53
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; rv:31.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/31.0
```

Below is a basic way to integrate `get_agent` with Scrapy. (It's not tested, but should point you in the right direction).

```python
import scrapy
from scrapy.http import Request

from agents import get_agent


EXAMPLE_URL = 'http://www.example.com'


def get_request(url):
    headers = {
        'User-Agent': get_agent(),
        'Referer': 'https://www.google.com/'
    }
    return Request(url, headers=headers)


class MySpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'myspider'

    def start_requests(self):
        yield get_request(EXAMPLE_URL)
```

**Edit**

Regarding user agents, looks like this might achieve the same thing but a bit more easily: [scrapy-fake-useragent](https://github.com/alecxe/scrapy-fake-useragent)